# How do you build Xalan-C with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: xml-parsing, xerces, xalan, xerces-c

I can not find proof that it's possible. After 40 hours of driving myself to insanity, I'm left with a situation where I cannot build the Localization project that supposedly builds a header file needed by the poorly named AllInOne project (which builds Xalan-C.lib, natch).

This library is software malpractice writ-large, I am desperate for an answer because it is a dependency in another library that I have no alternative to using.

Answer (score 7):

I have managed to build Xalan-C version 1.11, compatible with the latest version of Xerces-C (v3.1.1), in Visual Studio 2010. I don't know if it is possible with earlier versions, however these are the steps I followed in order to build with version 1.11:

- Xerces-C has to be built as a dynamic library to obtain the xerces-c_3_1D.dll file which MsgCreator.exe is dependent on.
- Clone the [github repository](https://github.com/apache/xalan-c) to obtain the source code of Xalan-C version 1.11.
- Set the environment variables `XERCESCROOT` and `XALANCROOT` in windows (not in Visual Studio).

  ```
   XERCESCROOT    The Xerces-C/C++ installation directory
   XALANCROOT     The Xalan-C/C++ source directory
  ```
- Open the Xalan-C solution in VS2010 and build the `MsgCreator` project.
- Copy the `xerces-c_3_1D.dll` file from the Xerces-C build and place it in the Xalan-C build folder, the same folder where `MsgCreator.exe` is located.

Now it is possible to generate the "missing" header files (LocalMsgIndex.hpp and LocalMsgData.hpp) that are needed to build the "AllInOne" project.

- Run MsgCreator.exe in cmd with the provided path to `XalanMsg_en_US.xlf` which is located in `$(XALANCROOT)\src\xalanc\NLS\en_US` and what [method](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/build_instruct.html#locale) to use when building the locale messages.

  ```
  MsgCreator.exe $(XALANCROOT)\src\xalanc\NLS\en_US\XalanMsg_en_US.xlf -TYPE=inmem
  ```

(I used `-TYPE=inmem`, but check to see what method is best suited for your solution)

- The header files are now generated and located in the build directory (where MsgCreator.exe resides). Copy or move them to `$(XALANCROOT)\src` and they should now be able to be located.
- Now build the `XalanMsgLib` project.
- And the last thing to do before the final build is to handle the including of `afxres.h` in the `AllInOne.rc` file (located in `$(XALANCROOT)\Projects\Win32\Res\AllInOne`). Visual Studio Express edition does not contain the MFC library which contains the `afxres.h` header. I simply changed it to `#include "windows.h"` instead.

And now it should be possible to build "AllInOne" successfully.

Comment: This helped me with `xalanc 1.12.0` and `Visual Studio 15 2017`. I set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to xerces intallation folder and copied `xerces-c_3_2D.dll` to `MsgCreator.exe` containing folder inside xalanc build folder

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this also and this is my recipe (VS2015 but look up the cmake docs for other IDEs)

> Note I was specifically targeting xerces 3.2.3 and xalan 1.12. Use git tag to get the versions you need

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/xerces-c.git
cd xerces-c
git checkout v3.2.3
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -BVS2015 -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
cd VS2015
devenv xerces-c.sln /Build Debug /Project ALL_BUILD
```

Because I use this with another build process that expects things in a certain way:
(assume you set up a target dir env called XERCESBUILD with bin/lib child dirs)

```
copy src\Debug\*.dll %XERCESBUILD%\bin
copy src\Debug\*.lib %XERCESBUILD%\lib
```

Then for xalan

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/xalan-c
cd xalan-c
git checkout Xalan-C_1_12_0
mkdir build
cd build
set PATH=%PATH%;%XERCESBUILD%\bin
cmake .. -BVS2015 -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -A x64 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=%JBCRELEASEDIR% -DXALAN_DEBUG=1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DXerce
sC_LIBRARY_DEBUG=%XERCESBUILD%\lib\xerces-c_3D.lib
cd VS2015
devenv xalan-c.sln /Build Debug /Project ALL_BUILD
```

Note the **xerces-c_3D.lib** is specifically the Debug build so remove the **D** when doing the Release build.

Comment: Even though the original post, and even this answer, are old, they still helped me today while trying to build Xalan-C with VS 2022. 

The key piece I was missing was the part that adds the location of the built Xerces-C DLL to the PATH variable. Without that, the in-memory locale message data would not build. The Xalan-C build documentation sort-of eludes to this, but not really, and the build error provides no real hints.

Like the original poster, I wasted a lot of time on this. Thankfully I ran across this answer that pointed me in the right direction.